# Remove all words before a specific pattern, after another pattern

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with many lines. Each line begin with a pattern `gi_[0-9]`, right after that, there is a tab, and after that a list of words, all separated with semi-colons. I would like only the 8 last words to remain (7 sections, because the last section has 2 words).

Here’s an example **input** file:

```
gi_1\tDog;Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish

gi_2\tPork;Black;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper
```

The **corresponding output** should be:

```
gi_1\tPink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish

gi_2\tBlack;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper
```

**Note**: I didn't find the way to insert a tab so I wrote \t instead, but there are tabulation marks in my file.

Comment: Can you add more details on what is blocking you ? What have you tried ? What are your results so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\t\)[^;]*;/\1/' file
```

The output:

```
gi_1    Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish
gi_2    Black;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper
```

---

- `\(.*\t\)` - capturing the needed part of the 1st section

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'sub("^[^;]*;", "", $2)' file.txt
```

- `sub("^[^;]*;", "", $2)` substitute the substring upto first `;` from start of the tab separated (`-F '\t'`) second field with null. `sub()` does the replacement in-place
- `-v OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator as tab
- The first field (and everything else) is kept as is

---

For the sake of completeness, making sure the first field is `gi_` followed by a digit:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^gi_[[:digit:]]$/ {sub("^[^;]*;", "", $2); print}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
gi_1    Dog;Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish
gi_2    Pork;Black;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper

% awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'sub("^[^;]*;", "", $2)' file.txt
gi_1    Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish
gi_2    Black;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper

% awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^gi_[[:digit:]]$/ {sub("^[^;]*;", "", $2); print}' file.txt
gi_1    Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish
gi_2    Black;White;Beige;Brown;Cyan;Purple;Red pepper
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized solution using grep with Perl flavor:

```
$ a="gi_1 \t Dog;Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish"
[s@SS data]$ echo $a | grep -P -o "((^gi_. \\\t )|(?<=[; ])(?:.(?!(([; ].+)){8}))+$)" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
gi_1 \t  Pink;Blue;Beige;Yellow;Orange;Red;Green irish
```

Note that this works with any number of words.

The non capture group and negative lookahead excludes any characters that do not follow a n repeated sequence of [; ] followed by any characters.

The positive lookahead at the begining get rids of the leading [; \t] character

The sed part gets rid of the new line in between.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed we can do it by looking for 6 semicolons in a do-until loop structure.

```
sed -e '
   :loop
      s/\t[^;]*;/\t/
      s/;/&/6
   Tloop
' yourfile
```